# How to separate value in NSMutableArray in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

My NsmutableArray having value like

```
myArray = "1,2,3,4,5....10";
```

these are comes from server. i want to separate it like

```
myarray = 1
          2
          3
          .
          .
          .
          10
```

how can i do this.

Comment: Your question is not understandable.

Comment: Is it a string or array?

Comment: Do you want separate objects from array like 1 separate, 2 separate and so on..??

Comment: @Gomathi this is array that contains value like "1,2,3.." these r different photoid's for diffrent photo's

Comment: do you want to remove the symbols like ( " " , ) ???

Comment: thanks for replying me @Maulik.. yes i want

Comment: can provide your response of server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your response would be in `NSString`

```
// it will remove the double qoutes from your response
NSString *temp = [responseString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""]; 

// gives a array of 1 2 3 ...
NSArray *aArray = [temp componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

hope it helps you...

Answer (score 1):

I guess [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594076/how-to-split-string-into-substrings-on-iphone) will help you.

The response from the server would be NSString. Split that with the separator.