# How to split items in a string separated by ","

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my App, data comes in String like this

```
"Hi,Hello,Bye"
```

I want to separate data by ","

How can I do that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use componentsSeparatedByString:

```
NSString *str = @"Hi,Hello,Bye";  
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];  
NSString *strHi = [arr objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *strHello = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *strBye = [arr objectAtIndex:2];
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The correct syntax is noted in the answer below: [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

Answer (score 7):

```
NSString *str = @"Hi,Hello,Bye";

NSArray *aArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

For more info, look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594076/how-to-split-string-into-substrings-on-iphone).

Answer (score 4):

Well, the naïve approach would be to use `componentsSeparatedByString:`, as suggested in the other answers.

However, if your data is truly in the CSV format, you'd do well to consider using a proper CSV parser, such as this one (which I wrote): https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Answer (score 2):

Use `[myString componentsSeparatedByString:@","]`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's NSString, you can use [componentsSeparatedByString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).

If it's std::string, you can iterate looking for the item (using [find_frst_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) and [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/))

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *components = [@"Hi,Hello,Bye" componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

[Apple's String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html) will help you get up to speed.