# Selecting up to a certain character in a string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

In the program I am working on I have a string in which I need to get only part of it out of. The string is formatted by a set of alphanumeric values, a dash, then more values.

Ex. ######-#########

I want to retrieve the values before and after the dash and store them in their own separate strings. This would be easy except the lengths of the two sets of values can vary and there is no limit to the lengths.

Another quick example of what I need help with.

Ex. 4837r99203-4747883391001
str1=4837r99203
str2=4747883391001

Getting only the vales after the dash. I can find answers to getting a certain length of string back. How would I do it if the lengths can vary? Thanks :)

Comment: What's worth +2 on this question? Is it "reward for not reading the documentation" day today?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to split items in a string separated by “,”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922131/how-to-split-items-in-a-string-separated-by)

Comment: Did you even glance at the [documentation for NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)????

Comment: Didn't have to be so rude about it guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`[NSString componentsSeparatedByString]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a)

```
NSString *testString = @"4837r99203-4747883391001";
NSArray *elements = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
// elements[0] = @"4837r99203"
// elements[1] = @"4747883391001"
```

Answer (score 0):

[[NSString componentsSeparatedByString:]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) will work for you. Like this:

```
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"]
```