# How to convert string to array in objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, string

How to convert string to array in objective C. i.e,I have a string,

```
NSString *str = @"Hi,How r u";
```

This should be converted into an array *NSMutableArray *arr* , where in

> arr[0] = "Hi"
>   arr[1] = ","
>   arr[2] = "How"
>   arr[3] = "r"
>   arr[4] = "u"

Can anybody help with the idea to crack this thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
NSString *str=@"Hi,How r u"; 
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *strSecond = [arr objectAtIndex:1];

NSMutableArray *arrSecond = [strSecond componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *strHow = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strAre = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *strYou = [arr objectAtIndex:2];

[arr removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[arr addObject:@","];
[arr addObject:strHow];
[arr addObject:strAre];
[arr addObject:strYou];
```

**arr** is the desired array.

Answer (score 7):

I guess [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594076/how-to-split-string-into-substrings-on-iphone) will help you.

```
NSString *str = @"Hi,How r u";
NSArray *listItems = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do,

```
NSString *str = @"Hi,How r u";
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

And, in order for this to work as you expect, there should be a `white-space` between `"Hi,"` and `"How"`. Your string should look like `@"Hi, How r u"`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
NSString *str2=@"Hi,How r u"; 
    NSMutableArray *arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[str2 componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@", "]]];
    NSLog(@"%@",arary);
```

if you want , as a object

```
NSString *str2=@"Hi,How r u";
    str2 = [str2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" , "];
    NSMutableArray *arary = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[str2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
    NSLog(@"%@",arary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NSString method componentsSeparatedByString. Take a look at the reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a).

Comment: i need Comma(,) also to be stored in the array. In this case i can't use componentsSeparatedByString.