# How to convert string to array in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSString *strdetails = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[products objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"details"]];

NSLog(@"%@",strdetails);
```

When I add on array but it's convert to previous data. But I want array not string.

Comment: Please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121693/decode-json-to-nsarray-or-nsdictionary. I hope it will sort out your problem

Comment: What you want from that. Please be specific.

Comment: The value for key `details` is a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: @GouravJoshi it'snot working

Comment: first link is my server response and second one is when i add on string

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712551/how-to-convert-string-to-array-in-objective-c

Comment: @raheem...it's not  right way...there are so many data in my server link

Comment: Plz check the solution I have posted

Comment: I have updated the answer plz check it

Comment: Post code where you are serializing the response from the web service. And also clearly state which value you want from the response

Answer (score 3):

Here is your code:

```
NSString *strdetails = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[products objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"details"]];

NSLog(@"%@",strdetails);
```

I update this code here:

```
NSData *objectData = [strdetails dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                      options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                        error:&jsonError];

 // Here you are getting dictionary, Now from this you will get array in this way
    // Print this dict
    NSLog(@"dict details =  %@",dict);
        NSArray * arrV = dict[@"variants"];
    // check your array
```

Comment: -[__NSCFString objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe9d2c6bc90....crash

Comment: i have print Nslog...is right but..sictionary is not proper

Comment: what is showing in dictionary...check this, is any kind of nil or type mismatch?

Comment: check first link..dictionary display like this

Comment: string object in dictionary thats why this  issue occered

Comment: which one string object, can you name that object?

Comment: NSDictionary * dict = [products objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"details"]; // Here you are getting dictionary, Now from this you will get array in this way
// Print this dict
NSLog(@"dict details =  %@",dict);

Comment: it's string when i add on server response in distionary

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are converting jsonString into Array I am using below function to convert my jsonString.

**ViewController**

```
public class func JSONParseArray(jsonString: NSString) -> [AnyObject]?{

if let data = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){

if let array = (try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0)))  as? [AnyObject] {
            return array
         }
    }
    return nil    
 }
```

**If You Want Specific value from Array:**

```
NSArray *outputArray = [array valueForKey:@"YourKey"];
```

Comment: please convert into objective c

Comment: no first link response from server and when i add into string then its display response like json string

Comment: @Maulik  i am using this function to avoid create extra lines for declare array and all stuff. Sorry for converting objective C it's my bad. Currently using Swift 3.0 code I written here. also which values

Comment: Also which value or array you want to use I will paste code here. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str=@"Hi,I LOVE IOS"; 
NSArray *arr = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *strSecond = [arr objectAtIndex:1];

NSMutableArray *arrIOS = [strSecond componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSString *strI = [arrIOS objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strLOVE = [arrIOS objectAtIndex:1];
NSString *strIOS = [arrIOS objectAtIndex:2];

[arr removeObjectAtIndex:1];
[arr addObject:@","];
[arr addObject:strI];
[arr addObject:strLOVE];
[arr addObject:strIOS];
```