# How to split string lines for twitter compose?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am trying to split the string to multilines when tweeting using the twitter composer in iOS 5+ but could not find the way to do it

i tried everything in this [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797318/how-to-split-a-string-literal-across-multiple-lines-in-c-objective-c/)

but nothing worked , its always gets to single line

is it possible to do it ?

update :

example for what i need

lets say i want to tweet this

"Hello John, Welcome to our website, we hope that you enjoy it"

instead of tweeting it like that , i want to look like this

"Hello John,

Welcome to our website,

we hope that you enjoy it"

Comment: You found a wrong answer to use as your example: the question that you linked talks about making a single line that appears in your code as multiple lines; my understanding is that you are looking for the opposite effect. You may want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/594123/335858) instead.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ok can u help me with it ? how can i tweet multilines using twitter compose ?

Comment: the question is not very clear. Show an example of the text before and after the splitting. I don't know what you want to achieve. Are you just looking for `@"\n"`?

Comment: @MatthiasBauch here is the example :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your question is just about how to create a multi-line NSString.
answer would be:

```
@"This is the first line.\nThis is the second line."
```

or

```
NSString *tweetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", myFirstLineString, mySecondLineString];
```

edit: for your updated question it would be that:

```
NSString *tweetString = "Hello John,\nWelcome to our website,\nwe hope that you enjoy it"
```

Comment: so really just looking for "\n" :-)