# How to fetch the last word from textfield

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have the following text in the text field

The Taj, Restraint, Renovation, Catch

How to get the Catch word alone from the text field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594076/how-to-split-string-into-substrings-on-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *str = @"The Taj, Restraint, Renovation, Catch";
 NSString *lastWord = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];
```

Comment: It's not advised to post answers containing code only, it's better if there is some explanation to how this code helps resolving the question.

Comment: @vesper: I will keep that thing in mind later on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 NSString *myString = @"Taj, Restraint, Renovation, Catch" ;   
__block NSString *lastWord = nil;

    [myString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, myString.length) options:(NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationReverse) usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange subrange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        lastWord = substring;
        *stop = YES;
    }];
```